# Copying all coordinates at once in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, xy, identify

I had a line with points and I want to get all of its coordinates by once,
The only way that I can copy the coordinates by this step
(Identify feature> right click the point that I choiced ,copy feature and paste it to get the coordinates,

but this step only selecting a coordinate , i want to get all coordinate,

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Are you using ArcMap or something else?

Comment: @PolyGeo the OP is using QGIS as it shows from the interface of Identify tool.

Comment: @ahmadhanb When you recognize the interface please don't hesitate to edit the software being used in.  I didn't think it was OOTB ArcMap but was not sure whether it was something like Supermap, QGIS, etc

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for your update. I will do it next time. :)

Comment: Without pictures this question seems harder to understand.

Comment: Thank you guys,I will be harder to learn it , yes i'm using QGIS, I will lable next time ,thank you/!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the attribute table of the point data
- Click on `Start Editing`
- Click on the corner to select all points (see image below)
- Click on copy
- Paste in text editor

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: But, when I open the attribute table I cant see (X,Y) coordinates, how to solve it,

Comment: You probably need to use the field calculator to create the X and Y fields. Use $x and $y geometry to create the new fields

Comment: @Jack the x and y are stored internally. When you copy and paste you will get the points with x and y

Comment: No you don't, you get WKT.

Comment: @bugmenot123 yes it's WKT. The OP showed his request as WKT (look at the history). It's not my fault that the OP removed the picture in his question

Comment: @Jack Please accept the answer if it solved the problem by checking the green mark under the answer.

Comment: @ahmadhanb ah, *sigh*. nice answer then :)

Comment: @ahmadhanb , I have clicked,thank you very much!! ^^